# Obtaining Process Details

Tags: process, operating-system

In general is there any way to get the details of the process (the process to which my program is translated to by the OS before execution). Is it possible to output the contents of the data structures (PCB for example) while my program is executing as a process?

Comment: it wud be nice to know what OS we r talking abt..

Comment: Right now am looking for Windows, Sir.

Comment: You can attach debugger to the process and dump all data what you want using debugger commands and priviate symbol files for your exe.

Comment: Thank you sir. But where can I get the information regarding attaching debugger to process?? Do you mean the one provided in the IDE (ex:Visual studio , Eclipse)?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running the program in linux .. you can then use   [readlf](http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/understanding-elf-using-readelf-and-objdump_125.html) and  [objdump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/09/objdump-examples/)  to get lot of information about the process(like its address space, dynamically linked libraries from glibc Ex:printf(), its symbol table etc)...
u can also see `cat /proc/process's pid` folder in linux, there to you can get a variety of information about the running process.
Ofcourse you can use a debugger to get the process's state as it is executing